# Ubercart cart not removing object in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

I am adding an item using the following code:

```
$some_data = array(
    'attributes' => array( 
        6 => $domainName, 
        1 => $domain->oid,
        2 => 705,
        7 => 706,
        8 => '',
        9 => '', 
        10 => '',
        11 => '',
    ),
);
$some_data = serialize($some_data);
uc_cart_add_item(
    $domainProductNID, 
    1,
    $some_data
);
```

It adds the item to the cart, with the correct configuration. However, if I then go to /cart and click on "remove", the item stays there. I am only able to remove it with:

```
uc_cart_empty();
```

Any idea why?

**UPDATE**

Removing the $some_data attribute and instead running:

```
uc_cart_add_item(
    $domainProductNID, 
    1
);
```

Does in fact work... so it must have something to do with the attributes being submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
$domainProductNID    =    27;
$form_state    =    array(
  'values'    =>    array(
        'nid'    =>    $domainProductNID,
        'qty'    =>    1,
        'attributes'    =>    array(    
             6    =>    $domainName,
             1    =>    $domain->oid,
             2    =>    705,
             7    =>    706,
             8    =>    '',  
             9    =>    '',  
             10    =>    '',
             11    =>    '',
        )
  ),

);
$node    =    node_load($domainProductNID);
drupal_form_submit("uc_product_add_to_cart_form",    $form_state,    $node);
```

Hope it helps someone else...